# Adding an outlet to a circuit

Tags: receptacle

I'd like to add an outlet behind our television.  I was going to pull power from an the outlet in the picture.  The outlet used to be switched, but the light switch has been re wired so it no longer controls the outlet.  How do I pull power from this outlet?
Also, I am out of 12/2 so I would like to use some 12/3 I have. I can do this, and either cut off the red or wirenut it right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy peasy.

The black wires in the back of the box are certainly always-hot.

The white wires are certainly neutral, and they are using the receptacle to be a splice (i.e. To replace a wire nut) while also supplying the receptacle.

The red is your switched hot from the switch, which you defeated.

You want to add a third hot and neutral from your new cable.  It would also be nice to power the receptacle straight off the always-hot (black) and abandon that extra loop up to the switch.  It would also be nice to stop using those unreliable and troublesome "back stab" wire connections.

You can't use two wiring methods (backstab and screw) on the same receptacle, so you can't splice 3 wires to a receptacle.  *The exception is the Leviton "screw-and-clamp" types, which support 4 wires per side and are about $3.00.  Alternately you could pigtail the receptacle.*

So I would add the new cable.   Join the now-3 black wires on the brass side of the Leviton screw-and-clamp, or the 4 wires (with pigtail from the receptacle) with a red wire nut.   Same thing with the whites.

*Red wire nuts are ideal to bind four #12s or #14s, it helps to tape any 2 wires together so you are trying to line up 2 bound pairs of wires instead of four loose ones.*

As for the red, I would splice the existing and your new red together with a yellow wire nut. Cap the red wire off in the new receptacle, and also go back into the switch box and cap it off there.  Now it's de-energized, but it's in the wall in case the next homeowner wants to set up a switched outlet at either old or your new location.

Comment: so I will cap red in the switch box.  Then I will add a new wire between the existing outlet and the new outlet.  I will take all (3) blacks and pigtail them, connected to brass screw.  I will take all (3) whites and pigtail to the other side of the outlet.  Sorry if this sounds like I'm just regurgitating what you said, but I just wanted to write t out myself to confirm I am following your directions.

Comment: @AlexanderBaker That sounds right.

Comment: I would like to vote for pigtailing the receptacle as it tends to follow the NEC intent closer. Also that Leviton type was the only type of receptacle I would allow my electricians to use in residential. Yes it's just that much better.